# Adding objects to WPF Panel displaying buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, panel

I want to add objects dynamicly to a ObservationCollection, which then should add buttons with a Content (value) of a field of the object to a panel.

App.xaml.cs
    using System.Windows;

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {

    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl Name="dashboardList">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

DashboadViewModel.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class DashboardViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Dashboard> Dashboards { get; set; }

        public DashboardViewModel()
        {
            LoadDashboards();
        }

        public void LoadDashboards()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Dashboard> dashboards = new ObservableCollection<Dashboard>();

            dashboards.Add(new Dashboard { Name = "Dashboard1" });
            dashboards.Add(new Dashboard { Name = "Dashboard2" });

            Dashboards = dashboards;
        }
    }
}
```

Dashboard.cs

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class Dashboard
    {
        public string Name;
    }
}
```

How do I get to create the buttons, am I on the right track with the ItemControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public string Name` should be changed to be a public property to support data binding:

```
public class Dashboard
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Besides that, an instance of DashboardViewModel should be assigned to the Window's `DataContext` property and the ItemsControl's `ItemsSource` property should be bound like this:

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:DashboardViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Dashboards}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If necessary, you can access the view model instance in the Window's code behind like this:

```
var vm = (DashboardViewModel)DataContext;
vm.LoadDashboards();
```